# MYSQL: How can I get data from a single column for different rows?

Tags: php, android, mysql

My MYSQL table is structured as so:

**User | Post | Time**

What MYSQL Query can I run to get all the data in the "posts" column in the table and how would this data be saved?

Also, how could I save the current time for the "time" column so I could later on get posts that are less than, say, 20 seconds old?

(My Android app uses PHP to get the posts from this table).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to tell us what types those columns are. Also what you are asking is quite basic and broad, perhaps you should research a little about php and mysql. I'm sure you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What MYSQL Query can I run to get all the data in the "posts" column
>   in the table.

```
select distinct posts from yourblogtable
```

Assuming your table name is `yourblogtable`

> Also, how could I save the current time for the "time" column

You can either use MySql `NOW()` function which will get Current Date and Time

OR

`CURDATE()` to get only the current date

OR

`CURTIME()` to get only the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Current Time: You can do it in php - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php or directly using SQL

MySQL Query: Quite basic

```
SELECT Post FROM table WHERE ...
```